# Match Perl identifier using re-search

Tags: search, regular-expressions, perl

I am trying to match a Perl identifier at the point, like `My::Module::dummy_func`. I'd like to start simple and require a valid identifier as follows:

- restricted to a single line
- starts with a space
- ends with a (

So if point is at a colon in this line:

```
my $a = My::Module::dummy_func(3)
```

I should get a match equal to `My::Module::dummy_func`.

Here is what I have

```
(defun get-perl-id-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg nil) (end nil))
    (save-excursion
      (if (re-search-forward "[A-Za-z0-9:_]*?(" (line-end-position) t)
          (setq end (- (point) 1))))
    (save-excursion
      (if (re-search-backward " [A-Za-z0-9:_]*?" (line-beginning-position) t)
          (setq beg (+ (point) 1))))
    (if (and beg end)
        (message (buffer-substring beg end)))))
```

This works for example if point is at a `:`, but if point is at the `$` in `$a` I get `$a = My::Module::dummy_func` whereas I would like to get a no match..

How can this be done?

Comment: I recommend using [`match-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html) to extract the string you matched. You can also use `match-beginning` and `match-end` to get positions of the start and end of the match. If you want to check if there is a match at point, use [`looking-at`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search).

Comment: @Constantine Thanks! I followed your recommendation, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the recommendations of @Constantine, here is an improved version of the function:

```
(defun get-perl-id-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg nil) (end nil))
    (if (looking-at "[A-Za-z0-9:_]*?(")
        (setq end (- (match-end 0) 1)))
    (if (looking-back "[-+=*/;[:space:]][A-Za-z0-9:_]*?" (- (line-beginning-position) 1))
        (setq beg (+ (match-beginning 0) 1)))
    (if (and beg end)
        (message (buffer-substring beg end))
      (message "No match"))))
```

This seems to work well.